# how to give permission write only to sqlite db in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

Here's my code:

```html
  Future<void> updatevalue(int b, int value) async {
    await initDatabase();

    await _db.rawQuery('UPDATE chines_recipe SET favorites=$value where recipe_id==$b');
  }
  
  query for updating column
```

The log output;

> E/SQLiteLog( 1902): (8) statement aborts at 25: [UPDATE chines_recipe
> SET favorites=1 where recipe_id==2] attempt to write a readonly
> database E/SQLiteQuery( 1902): exception: attempt to write a readonly
> database (code 8); query: UPDATE chines_recipe SET favorites=1 where
> recipe_id==2 E/flutter ( 1902):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
> DatabaseException(attempt to write a readonly database (code 8)) sql
> 'UPDATE chines_recipe SET favorites=1 where recipe_id==2' args []
> E/flutter ( 1902): #0      wrapDatabaseException
> (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11:7) E/flutter ( 1902):
>  E/flutter ( 1902): #1
> SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawQuery.
> (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:404:30) E/flutter (
> 1902):

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem and provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t post the full code but I assume you might missed the parameter

> readOnly = false.

Can you try something like this?

```
db = await openDatabase(path, readOnly: false, );
```

Comment: There are also many sources that show you an example how to create a database and update values. I would also suggest checking those.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite